# Get data from JSON file in JQuery

Tags: json

I try to print some alert to verify my data. I got them like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [
            {
                color: "red",
                value: "#f00"
            },

            {
                color: "black",
                value: "#000"
            }
        ];

        alert(data.red);
    });
```

The alert displays "undefined" because it's not a simple JSON, it's an object. How can I get for example the value of color red ?

Comment: Did you mean `data[0].color` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's undefined because you're doing it wrong. Try

```
alert(data[0].color); // spits out "red"
```

You've got an array of objects, and you're trying to treat it as just an array, and using the VALUES as if they were keys.